# Will the AT&T HTC Aria Froyo (2.2) official upgrade solve the Bluetooth reset issue? will it allow free tethering as the unofficial 2.2?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, bluetooth, att, htc-aria

Hi
I couldn't wait and dowloaded the 2.2 upgrade for my AT&T HTC Aria just to find out the [official one](http://www.wireless.att.com/answer-center/main.jsp?t=solutionTab&solutionId=KB115830) came one a few weeks later.

The only reason I want to upgrade is the [Bluetooth reset bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9503) (phone reboots / resets after walking away from a bluetooth source, e.g. when I exit the car while using [Vlingo](http://vlingo-en.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/747/p/180/session/L3NpZC9DSENIazVlaw==/sno/0) (with car handsfree), my phone resets!

**So my quetions are**

1. What is the best way to solve the Bluetooth reset issue? Will the official upgrade fix it?
2. Assuming most chances it will, will it hurt my phone in any way? (will it unroot it? will it block tethering?)

Comment: what happens when you don't use Vlingo?

Answer (score 1):

The official update will almost certainly unroot and not allow free WiFi tether.  I'll let someone with experience speak to the bluetooth issues.